# Suponer una evaluación de 30 puntos y que cada pregunta correcta equivale a un (1) punto. listar las notas obtenidas de los alumnos escala es del 70%

Tags: base-de-datos

cual puede ser el código que me puede servir
intente con el siguiente codigo:

```
*`select rut,numero_correctas,numero_incorrectas,
case
when (numero_correctas/30)>=0.7
then trunc((numero_correctas/30)*7.5 - 0.5,3)
else trunc((numero_correctas/30)*5 + 1,3)
end as nota
from evaluacion;`
```

Comment: Especifica la base de datos que estás usando, y agrega su etiqueta para recibir mejores ayudas. De paso tambien la estructura de la tabla. Recuerda que debes poner un [example] válido.  Léete [ask] y [tour] para entender la mecánica del sitio, gracias.

Comment: Hola Estimado Max, bienvenido a la comunidad. es un poco difusto el plantamiento del problema, qué datos usas para la lógica y el resultado esperado.